# JqueryMobile woes (1.0.1) ... not working properly in Eclipse/ADT/Android Simulation (2.3 - API Level 10)

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, cordova, android-emulator

Status:
New to jqueryMobile ... almostExpert in JS/Jquery.
New to Phone-dev ... internet-dev for quite a few years.

Tools:
Phonegap 1.4.1
jQueryMobile css (only a single theme "a")
Jquery 1.6.4 (tried 1.7.1 and heard in some place this might be the prob, but it wasn't)
JQueryMobile 1.0.1
Eclipse Indigo/ADT - Android 2.3 Simulation with 500MB SD-Card Simulation

Scenario:
Basic Listview/Collapsible(-Set) built dynamically after Ajax-Call with XML-Data.
(Now I also tried to overcome the prob by doing a multipage setup with a simple image as first page and my xml-driven collapsible-set on the second page --- same html)

Behaviour/Challenge:
I get the colors from CSS, and some basic element sizing... lists still appear as li-elements (with their reference stars/dots) and plain_old_links.
collapsible behaviour not responding on clicks and styling also virtually not existing...
multipage not working ... everything displayed in a row, one element beneath the other ...
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg() ... not working - or at least I see nothing that would hint to this having any visible effect

Summary:
Pretty much nothing I tried works, if I didn't like black humour ... :)

Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zv625/

Something is totally going wrong here and I have no clue what ... please help :)

Comment: I have some notes to your JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Zv625/2/ Some of the files are missing or have already been added, You are also calling some functions before they are defined, last document.ready is not used by jQM http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: thx for the input/feedback
I don't get what you mean by some of the files are missing? (the libraries I didn't paste into fiddle, though I included them apart from phonegap of which I couldn't find a "cloud-based"-readymade URI)
Calling functions before they are defined is perfectly valid in Javascript, it is called "variable hoisting".
your change to calling the eventInit plainly in the header would possibly fail, cause if the function would try to do something to the dom (as for example it does in the callbacks) it would possibly fail if you don't wait for $(document).ready ...

Comment: also, the jqm alternative to document.ready (so I read on jqm) is pageinit, which (according to the doc) isn't triggered on the initial data-role="page" element, so I really need document.ready, and that didn't seem to be a problem in the simulator

Comment: last, the document.addEventListener(deviceready) which binds/calls onDeviceReady which is commented out in the jsfiddle ... I do use it and not comment it out in the live version ... I replaced it with the direct init-call in the $(document).ready for jsfiddle purposes, since phonegap won't work without an android environment and so I thought it might just work this way in the browser (though it plainly doesn't) :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue, after trying Titanium Studio and Sencha Touch a bit and finding them not meeting my tastes.
After picking it all apart bit by bit and resembling it to the multipage template on jquerymobile itself - testing it all in chrome ... - it still didn't work ...
Almost the last thing that differed from the original was the sources for jqm itself ...
I included the downloaded sources and the site included some code.jquery.com links ...
I swapped those and et voila, suddenly it worked: My downloads were corrupt ...
I will now try to download again and will maybe find out more, but expect it to work.

edit: I needed the jquery structure file!

Comment: In fact I tried different downloads and it still didn't work until I found I was missing one file right from the beginning --> the jquery.mobile.structrue-1.0.1.css file!!